# error in computing difference between two date time stamp [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000] columns in seconds in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which has two columns 'Etime' and 'Stime' which contains end and start timestamp and sample of which is shown below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Etime': ['2019-08-23 00:00:06.773', '2019-09-19 00:00:16.083', '2019-08-29 00:00:07.043', '2019-10-01 00:00:14.777','2019-08-15 00:00:57.050'],
'Stime': ['2019-08-22 23:59:41.983', '2019-09-18 23:59:44.007', '2019-08-28 23:59:02.863', '2019-09-30 23:59:05.187', '2019-08-14 23:59:20.217']})
```

What I want to do it to create an another columns 'Duration' which should contain the difference of start and endtime in seconds and final dataset should look like as below:

```
Etime                        Stime                      Duration
2019-08-23  00:00:06.773     2019-08-22 23:59:41.983    25
2019-09-19  00:00:16.083     2019-09-18 23:59:44.007    32
2019-08-29  00:00:07.043     2019-08-28 23:59:02.863    04
2019-10-01  00:00:14.777     2019-09-30 23:59:05.187    10
2019-08-15  00:00:57.050     2019-08-14 23:59:20.217    37
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
df['STS'] = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df['Stime']).dt.time.astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()
df['EDS'] = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df['Etime']).dt.time.astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()
df['Duration'] = round(df['EDS'] - df['STS'], 0)
```

Which is giving me wrong output as follows:

```
Etime                      Stime                         Duration
2019-08-23 00:00:06.773    2019-08-22 23:59:41.983      -86375
2019-09-19 00:00:16.083    2019-09-18 23:59:44.007      -86368
2019-08-29 00:00:07.043    2019-08-28 23:59:02.863      -86336
2019-10-01 00:00:14.777    2019-09-30 23:59:05.187      -86330
2019-08-15 00:00:57.050    2019-08-14 23:59:20.217      -86303
```

What is wrong I am doing here?

Can there be a better way for this?

Comment: make sure `Etime` and `Stime` are datetime types and just do `(df['Etime'] - df['Stime']).dt.total_seconds().round(0)`

Comment: thanks for help, I got the error this way, : `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` .  just to confirm, I also checked `df['Etime'].isna().unique()`, which gave me : `array([False])`

Comment: you need `df['Etime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Etime'])`, and same for `Stime`

Comment: Still I am getting the same answer as above in my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
df['Duration'] = [(datetime.strptime(df.loc[x,'Etime'], date_format ) -
                     datetime.strptime(df.loc[x,'Stime'], date_format)).seconds
                         for x in df.index]
```